# Why is the same app different sizes on different devices

Tags: ios, app-store

I released my first app in the AppStore right before Apple's holiday break. On the iPhone the size of app listed in the App Store is 15MB. However, the exact same app on iPad is 28.8MB according to AppStore page.

Why is there a the huge size difference if both the apps have everything the same?

Comment: Are you sure the image resolutions are all the same?

Answer (score 3):

*Do they?* I do not think so.

Apple sends only the images along with the app file that the particular devices needs. The non-retina devices will have really tiny size while the app for the iPhone 6S Plus will be a lot larger.

The term used for that procedure is [**`App Thinning`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html). What I mentioned regarding the images is a part of that and called **`Slicing`**

Answer (score 1):

Apple has introduced a concept called [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) with iOS 9. It contains three strategies to reduce the download size of you App:

1. Slicing: In short only the images and resources needed for a specific target device are delivered. If someone downloads the App with iOS 8 or earlier, the full package will be downloaded

> Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target device

2. Bitcode: If active, Apple can optimise your code for a specific device. For example deploy with 32 or 64 Bit compiled code
3. On demand data sources: Must be used explicitely by you